Horror Film Identification - Mother & Children Slowly Floating Towards Ceiling
Both my mother and I vaguely remember a horror film we watched, most likely 2007 or earlier, and both of our memories match. We can only remember one specific scene (maybe a few minutes long or so), here goes:
The scene shows a woman in her bedroom on her own using her hairdryer, and then also shows 1 or 2 children in the other room, minding their own business having fun. Some seconds later, the kids start to float slowly towards the ceiling - this prompts them to start screaming. The woman hears the cries and then tries to open her bedroom door, which for some reason she is unable to open the door. She then also starts to slowly float to the ceiling like the children.
I know for sure it's not something I've watched in the past 10 years as I've not watched any horrors in that time period. Sorry for being so vague but that's literally all I remember. No faces, actor names etc.

I believe the movie you're describing is Poltergeist (1982)
Scene hairdryer
Scene float to the ceiling
Wikipedia:

Shortly thereafter, the Freelings begin the process of moving
  elsewhere by packing up their belongings. During their last night in
  the house, Steven leaves for the office in order to quit his job and
  Dana goes on a date, leaving Diane, Robbie, and Carol Anne alone in
  the house. The "Beast" then ambushes Diane and the children, aiming
  for a second kidnapping by attempting to restrain Robbie and Diane.
  Robbie is attacked by a clown doll in his bedroom, and Diane is
  attacked by an unseen force that moves her up the wall and over the
  ceiling in her room. The unseen force drives Diane to the backyard
  dragging her into the swimming pool. Skeletons surround her as she
  tries to swim to escape, but she manages to climb out of the pool and
  make her way back into the house. She rescues the children, and they
  eventually escape to the outside only to discover coffins and rotting
  corpses erupting out from the ground in their yard and throughout the
  neighborhood.






Thank you so much! That's exactly the film I was (vaguely) describing! It's all coming back to me now. You genius!
